# What "gotchas" should I be aware of when writing to the same file descriptor in a parent and child process?

Tags: c++, c, linux

Background: I'm working in C (and very C-ish C++) on Linux. The parent process has an open file descriptor (edit: not file descriptor, actually a `FILE` pointer) that it writes data to in a "sectioned" format. The child process uses it for this same purpose. As long as the child process is running, it is guaranteed that the parent will not attempt to write more data to its copy of the `FILE` pointer. The child exits, the parent waits for it, and then it writes more data to the file.

It *appears* to be working correctly, but I'm still suspicious of it. Do I need to re-seek to the end in the parent? Are there any synchronization issues I need to handle?

Comment: An authoritative answer is not possible without a [mre]. The only thing that can be authoritatively stated is that if a file is opened in append mode then no explicit seek is required.

Comment: You say "file descriptor" but that is a POSIX concept.  C only has `FILE` pointers.  (C doesn't have parents and children either).  Without actual code, though, it is not clear what you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Yes, it's a `FILE` pointer.

Comment: Changing from 'file descriptor' to 'file pointer' complicates the answers.  There are a lot more caveats around.  This sort of change is why we like to see the code — a minimal version of the code.  If we see file streams in the code, we can get clarification.  Without the code, we have to take you at your word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>*The question changed from 'file descriptors' to 'file pointers' or 'file streams'.  That complicates any answer.*</sup>

#### File Descriptors

File descriptors come from Unix in general, and Linux in particular, and a lot of the behaviour is standardized by POSIX.  You say that the parent and child processes share the same file descriptor.  That's not possible; file descriptors are specific to one process.

Suppose the parent opens a file (assume the file descriptor is `3`) and therefore there is also a new open file description; then the parent process forks.  After the fork, each process has a separate file descriptor (but they're both using file descriptor `3`), but they share the same open file description.  Yes: 'open file descriptors' and 'open file descriptions' are different!  Every open file descriptor has an open file description, but a single open file description can be associated with many open file descriptors, and those descriptors need not all be associated with the same process.

One of the critical bits of data in the open file description is the current position (for reading or writing — writing is what matters here).
Consequently, when the child writes, the current position moves for both the parent and the child.  Therefore, whenever the parent does write, it writes after the location where the child finished writing.

**What you are seeing is guaranteed.**  At least under the circumstances where the parent opens the file and forks.

Note that in the scenario discussed, the `O_APPEND` flag was not needed or relevant.  However, if you are worried about it, you could open the file with the `O_APPEND` flag, and then each normal write (not written via `pwrite()`) will write the data at the current end of the file.  This will work even if the two processes do not share the same open file description.

POSIX specification:

- [`open()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html)
- [`fork()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html)
- [`write()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html)
- [`dup2()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)
- [`pwrite()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pwrite.html)

#### File Streams

File streams come with buffering which makes their behaviour more complex than file descriptors (which have no buffering).

Suppose the scenario is like this pseudo-code (error handling omitted):

```
FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "w");
…code block 1…
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0)
{
    …child writes to file…
    …child exits…
}
else
{
    …parent waits for child to exit…
    …parent writes to file…
}
```

The de facto implementation of a file stream uses a file descriptor (and you can find the file descriptor using `fileno(fp)`).  When the `fork()` occurs, it is important that there is no pending data in the file stream — use `fflush(fp)` before the `fork()` if any of the code in '`…code block 1…`' has written to the file stream.

After the `fork()`, the two processes share the same open file description, but they have independent file descriptors.  Of necessity, they have identical copies of the file stream structure.

When the child writes to its copy of the file stream, the data is stored in its buffer.  When the buffer fills, or when the child closes the stream (possibly by exiting in a coordinated manner, not using `_exit()` or its relatives or as a result of a signal), the child's file data is written to the file.  That process will move the current position in the shared open file description.

When the parent is notified that the child has exited, then it can write to its file buffer.  That information will be written to disk when the buffer fills or is flushed, or when the parent closes the file stream.  Since it will be using the same open file description as the child was using, the write position will be where the child left it.

So, as before, what you're seeing is guaranteed as long as you are careful enough.

In particular, calling `fflush(fp)` before the `fork()` is crucial if the file stream has been used by the parent before the `fork()`.  If you don't ensure that the stream is flushed, you will get unflushed data written twice, once by the child and once by the parent.

It is also crucial that the child exits cleanly — closing the file stream and hence flushing any unwritten data to the file.  If the child does not exit cleanly, there may be buffered data that never gets written to the file.  Similarly, if the parent doesn't exit cleanly, there may be buffered data from the parent that never gets written to the file.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about POSIX file descriptors, then each `write` call to a file descriptor is atomic and affects the underlying kernel resource object indepently of what other processes might do with file descriptors that refer to the same object.  If two processes do `write` at approximately the same time, the operations will get ordered by the kernel with one happening completely (though it might write less data than requested) and then the other happening.

In your case, it sounds like you are synchronizing such that you know all parent writes happen either before the child has started (before `fork`) or after it has completed (after `wait`), which guarentees the ordering of the `write` calls.

Comment: Why would it write less data than requested? Does the kernel interrupt itself for write operations?

Comment: @user8393252: if you request a write  of more data than can fit in the buffer, it might write as much as can fit and return a short write.  Depends on what the descriptor refers to (pipe, socket, file, other device...)  For a pipe, any write of `PIPE_BUF` bytes or less will not return a short write.

Comment: So you’re just saying that it may defer to another write request if its capacity is exceeded by a single one?